# New files in old Microsoft Exchange Mailbox Database folder

Tags: exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2011

Our office is currently running on SBS 2011 Standard x64, on this server we have Microsoft Exchange 2010 and a virtual environment in which Terminal Server is running.

I have been advised that to increase performance of the OS (C:\ - mirrored), that the mailbox database can be moved to a different physical drive that are installed (F:\ - mirrored)

I have done this, but I have noticed that since doing this, the new database location wasn't seeing files with up-to-date timestamps but files with new time stamps were showing up in the original database location.

The mailboxes were moved via the following process: Open 'Exchange Management Console' and using the tree in the left pane, clicking 'Organization Configuration' and then highlighting 'Mailbox'. In the top panel on the right hand side, in 'Database Management' I right-click on each mailbox and have the option of 'Move Database Path..' On selecting that option I can alter the Database File Path and from there I changed it to another physical drive. The log Folder Path was left on the original drive under C:

Is there a reason that this is happening or has the database move not been as successful as the GUI leads me to believe?

As usual, any and all assistance is greatfully received.

Regards

tmd

Added note: This has now been solved. The move was successful and I am told the files were simply re-indexing.

Comment: `the new location isn't seeing any modifications but files are still being altered in the old location on C:.` - Can you give us more detail on what that means? Also, how did you move the files? Is the F: drive a separate physical drive/drive array?

Comment: People answer here freely of their own time and expertise. If you want `priority` responses then maybe your best course of action would be to contact Microsoft PSS and open a support case. Secondarily, I asked these two questions so that I and others had a better understanding of the problem, not because I had a ready answer for you.

Comment: What process, exactly, did you perform to move the files?

Comment: @CraigSunderland If this is resolved, could you please post the steps you took to resolve it as an answer and then accept that answer?

Comment: @EEAA thank you for letting me know that I can do that. I wasn't aware you could answer your own question and accept it. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351168(v=exchg.141).aspx

Did you move both the EDB and log paths? Did you do this step below?

> After the database is moved, the Indexing service maintains a lock on the Catalog files. Before you can delete these files from the old location, you must restart the Microsoft Exchange Search Indexer service.

Run `Get-MailboxDatabase |select *path*` and review the results to make sure they are currently where you expect them to be, or to find out where they actually are.

Comment: mfinni, thank you for your concise answer. It is pretty much how I had done things however the step of restarting the service was skipped due to having to reboot the server anyway.

Appreciated!